# Change the href attribute of <a> tags in an html document

Tags: php, html, dom, replace, hyperlink

I'm using `file_get_contents` to get a certain file's contents -- so far that is working.

Now I want to search the file and replace all `<a href="` with  `<a href="site.php?url=` before showing the file.

How can I do this? I know I should use some kind of `str_replace` or even `preg_replace`. But I don't know how to actually search and do it for the file I'm getting with `file_get_contents`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) returns a string containing the file's content.

So, you can work in this string using whichever string manipulation function you'd want, like the ones you talked about.

Something like this, using str_replace, would probably do :

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');

$new_content = str_replace('<a href="', '<a href="site.php?url=', $content);

echo $new_content;
```

But note it will only replace the URL in the `href` attribute when that attribute is the first one of the `<a` tag...

Using a regex **might** help you a bit more ; but it probably won't be perfect either, I'm afraid...

If you are working with an HTML document and want a "full" solution, using [`DOMDocument::loadHTML`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) and working with DOM manipulation methods might be another (a bit more complex, but probably more powerful) solution.

The answers given to those two questions might also be able to help you, depending on what you are willing to do :

- [underlinks also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245452/php-filegetcontents-also-get-the-pictures)
- [file_get_contents - also get the pictures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245452/php-filegetcontents-also-get-the-pictures)

---

**EDIT** after seeing the comment :

If you want to replace two strings, you can pass arrays to the two first parameters of `str_replace`. For instance :

```
$new_content = str_replace(
    array('<a href="', 'Pages'), 
    array('<a href="site.php?url=', 'TEST'), 
    $content);
```

With that :

- '`<a href="`' will be replaced by '`<a href="site.php?url=`'
- and '`Pages`' will get replaced by '`TEST`'

And, quoting the manual :

> If search  and replace  are arrays,
>   then str_replace() takes a value from
>   each array and uses them to do search
>   and replace on subject . If replace 
>   has fewer values than search , then an
>   empty string is used for the rest of
>   replacement values. If search  is an
>   array and replace  is a string, then
>   this replacement string is used for
>   every value of search .

If you want to replace all instances of '`<a href="`', well, it's what `str_replace` does by default :-)

Comment: I have one more question. Though this was a very good answer that helped me on the way. If i would want to do 2 replacements, how would that work? 2 replacements at one time.

Comment: I editing my answer with a couple more informations, that might help you with that :-) Have fun!

Answer (score 4):

```
$text = file_get_contents('some_file');
$text = str_replace('<a href="', '<a href="site.php?url=', $text);
```

Comment: Watch out for case sensitivity and more complex cases like '<a  href="'(two spaces). If these are relevant, you may want to consider using str_ireplace, regular expressions or more complex parsing solutions.

Comment: Also, you'll need to urlencode() the url in the new href otherwise you'll probably end up with other problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
$new_content = preg_replace('!(<a\s*[^>]*)href="([^"]+)"!','\1 href="site.php?url=\2"', $content);
```

I think this should do the trick:

- it replaces the href of a link, no matter where it is located
- e.g. works on <a href=".." , <a style="" href="..."

Comment: HTML attribute values may contain plain `>` characters.

Comment: I've been parsing quite a lot of websites with regular expressions, never stumbled upon a < or > in an attribute value. Could you show me an example if you could recall any?

Comment: No, \1 and \2 should not be url encoded in any way. In the context of the RegExp engine they mean Match #1 and Match #2. The example above translated roughly to match a string like '(<a )href="(somepage.html)"' (parentheses show the matching characters) and replace it with "(The first match: '<a ')href="site.php?url=(The second match: 'somepage.html')", which will result: "<a href="site.php?url=somepage.html". If we urlencode the \1 and \2 the result will be: "%5C1href="site.php?url=%5C2"

Answer (score 1):

For stability/reliability, it is advisable to use a DOM parser instead of regex or basic string replacement functions because they are DOM-ignorant.

It will not be the most performant solution, but it is clean, readable, easy to maintain, and least likely to fail.  The performance hit is not likely to be noticeable to your end users.

The snippet to follow is an adaptation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61968152/2943403).

No `preg_` or `str_replace()` functions are called.  I use Xpath to filter out any unwanted href matches.  Calling `http_build_query()` is a clean way of generating an encoded url query string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/m1HZv))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<div>
    <img src="icons/example.svg">
    <a href="http://www.example.com">a link</a>
    <link href="css/example.css">
    <iframe src="http://www.example.com/default.htm"></iframe>
</div>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//a/@href') as $attr) {
    $attr->value = "site.php?" . http_build_query(['url' => $attr->value]);
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<div>
    <img src="icons/example.svg">
    <a href="site.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com">a link</a>
    <link href="css/example.css">
    <iframe src="http://www.example.com/default.htm"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the remote document on your website but keep the links of that document intact, better use the [`BASE` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-BASE) to declare the base URI:

```
<base href="http://example.com/path/to/remote/document">
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the code sent by bisko but, no matter about the enclose ', " or nothing in href

```
$text = '<a href="http://www.europanet.com.br">Europanet</a>     <a target="_blank" href=\'http://www.webjump.com.br\'>Webjump</a>
<a id="link" href=http://www.euforia.com.br target="_top">Euforia</a>';
$text = preg_replace('|(<a\s*[^>]*href=[\'"]?)|','\1site.php?url=', $text);
```

Comment: Yes, that's awesome! But how about doing the same with img-tags? Is it just to change the a and href in the preg_replace. And how about doing all that in one? With img-tags AND href-tags! Thank u for ur answer.