# How to search for <link> tag and prepend

Tags: php, html, regex, replace, hyperlink

I'm using this code to prepend the URL variable inside the src tag for images. Now I want an regex code that makes it possible to search for `<link>` tags and add the URL variable inside the link tags href attribute. This is the code I have for the images; might help explain things:

```
function imgprepend_proxy($matches2) {
   $url = (substr($_GET['url'], 0, 7) == 'http://') ? $_GET['url'] : "http://{$_GET['url']}";
    $prepend2 = $matches2[2] ? $matches2[2] : $url;
    $prepend2 = $prepend2 . '/';

    return $matches2[1] . $prepend2 . $matches2[3];
}



$new_content = preg_replace_callback(
    '|(href=[\'"]?)(https?://)?([^\'"\s]+[\'"]?)|i',
    'prepend_proxy',
    preg_replace_callback(
        '|(src=[\'"]?)(https?://)?([^\'"\s]+[\'"]?)|i',
        'imgprepend_proxy',
        $content
    )
);
```

Comment: "This code i have ... might give u hints."  Ooh, I love a good puzzle.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254890/pregreplacecallback-do-twice/1254923#1254923 - This is where the code was from.

Looks like a bit of a homework assignment type of task.

Comment: hihi, i just want some help. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that your current code should prepend the URL to every src attribute (by the imgprepend_proxy function) and every href attribute (by prepend_proxy), regardless of HTML element (tag). However, there's no prepend_proxy function in the code you posted. Perhaps it doesn't exist at all?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254890/pregreplacecallback-do-twice/1254923#1254923

Comment: Okay... Now I'm really confused. The author got this question answered yesterday, so why is (s)he asking it again?